# What does 'if not data: break' mean?

Tags: python

I found this Python code [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication).

I don't understand what `if not data: break` in line 18 means.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvotes? I think it's a legitimate question. +1

Comment: It's `if not data:`, not `if no data:`.

Comment: Downvotes was for the fact that the poster did not describe the problem with enough clarity to understand the answer to said problem.  I edited the question so it is coherent.  Questions on stackoverflow should follow the following guidelines: (http://sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Compilable, Example)

Comment: @MoayadMardini I didn't downvote, but one possible reason would be that Pano was not very specific about what he doesn't understand. Does he understand what `if` does? Does he know what `not` does? Does he know what `break` does?

Comment: It means that if there is nothing received from the previous line the loop will break and the print statement will not be executed.

Comment: `if not data` is equivalent to `if not bool(data)` which is equivalent to `if bool(data) == False`.
<br>
`any('', 0, 0.0, False, None, [], (), {})` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 4):

It just checks if the `data` received is empty, if yes, then it breaks out of the loop. Much like checking for an empty string.

```
>>> not ""
True
>>> bool("")
False
```

If `data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` gives an empty string, the `while` loop is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

It means if the most recent attempt to receive data on the connection returned no data, break out of the loop attempting to receive more data.

See

```
while 1:
    while block
```

is a while loop with a condition that always evaluates to true. Therefore, this is an infinite loop which will evaluate `while block` on every iteration.

Except in our case, `while block` has a `break` in it. Should that `break` be hit, it will break out of the loop. Lets look at the `while block`:

```
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data:
        break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
```

This block is saying receive data on the connection `conn` reading at most `BUFFER_SIZE` bytes. If there was no data received, `not data` evaluates to true and we execute the `if` body. In this case, it's the `break` statement we have been discussing so we break out of the loop and stop receiving data. If the `if` condition evaluates to false, the message `"received data:"` followed by the data received is printed to the console. Finally, the data is echoed back to the other endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It means if the data is empty, null or equivalent, the while loop will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

This is tpc socket code to read the client request forever.
So the code `conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)` return -1 if client got disconnected or client server pipeline breaked, so in that case `if not data` becomes true and then it will break the while loop and stop listing client request. Hope you are clear now.